# Sampling from graphical model

Tags: sampling, graphical-model

I have just started to work on graphical models, more specifically on a Poisson Markov Network, which is specified by the conditional distributions like this: 
 
$$p\left ( X_{j} |X_{k}=x_{k},\forall k\neq j,\Theta \right )\sim Poisson\left ( e^{\theta _{j}+\sum _{j\neq k}\theta _{kj}x_{k}} \right )$$

If I have specific value of $ \theta$, am I wright to obtain data sample from that network by Gibbs sampler?
It feels like it is correct to do that like this, but I obtain some strange results in further  usage of simuated data.

Comment: From further investigation of literature,  it seems that in order to have a samples from random Markov fields I need to turn to the perfect sampling - at least no luck to find a paper where Gibbs sampler is used to do that. However, I do not understand why to use perfect simulation instead of Gibbs sampling? If I have a conditional distributions for Markov Random Field, than it seems netural to exploit that in order to simulate the network by Gibbs sampler.

Comment: Perfect simulation and Gibbs sampling are compatible, the latter being a tool used by the former. You only need to use perfect sampling if you require iid data. Otherwise, Gibbs sampling will generate a dependent sample, distributed from the target after a while (easily deduced from monitoring the values of the posterior density).